# I would like to ask the meaning of the following phrase

Tags: meaning

"There are also people, he said, who want to keep their meal off the books — if they're having an affair, for example." What does that mean?

This is one phrase of NPR programmes.

Comment: Which part of it don't you understand, & what has your research told you, so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Off the books' means that their is no record kept of a transaction. For example, in your sentence, a person having an affair may pay cash for a meal instead of paying by credit card. If they paid by credit card their spouse or partner may see the transaction when it appears an the credit card statement and ask about it. By paying by cash they avoid any paper trail that could lead to such embarrassing questions.

Similarly, covert government agencies will run some operations 'off the books' or 'off the record' so that there is no official record of the operation that they can be questioned about.

Comment: As a student, I worked as a barman "off the books". My pay was partly recorded in the pub accounts as cleaning expenses, and partly provided by the sale of 'phantom' barrels of beer provided semi-unofficially by brewery employees in return for cash.  This was before electronic tills. The books were maintained by hand.